# Hibernate @Id via inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to duplicate something you can do in .Net but not having much luck.

Is the following not possible in Java or am I just missing something?  When I run it I get told there is no identifier specified for entity Group.

```
public abstract class RCEntity
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   //getters & setters
}

@Entity 
public class Group extends RCEntity {
}
```

Comment: On a side note, these annotations are part of the JPA standard, and not necessarily Hibernate specific.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the annotation **@MappedSuperclass** to your super class, i.e.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class RCEntity
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   //getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From [this section in the docs:](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier)

> Any class in the hierarchy non annotated with @MappedSuperclass nor @Entity will be ignored.