# How to use Entity tag with objects that extend another class? (Spring & Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, entity

I have an abstract class `User` which is extended by `RegularUser` and `BusinessUser`. The tables in MySQL are `RegularUser` and `BusinessUser`. I created the abstract `User` class as both `RegularUser` and `BusinessUser` contain similar data.

So if I were to have the Id annotation in the `User` class like so:

```
public abstract class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long userId;
    // ...
}
```

And the Entity/table declaration in the `BusinessUser` and `RegularUser` classes like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BUSINESS_USER")
public class BusinessUser extends User {
    // ...
}
```

and this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REGULAR_USER")
public class RegularUser extends User {
    // ...
}
```

Would this work properly? Or do both declarations need to be in the same class? Is this possible/allowed? I'm simply a bit confused on how to approach this.

Comment: The id annotation, IIRC, needs to belong in the concrete class declaration and not the abstract class. Then, you can use abstract methods for get and setid without having an id field in the abstract class.

Comment: @Compass so I should move the Id to the BusinessUser and the RegularUser classes then? Have those classes hold the Id's so I can set both the Id and Entity annotations in those classes? I'll try this out and let you know how it works! Thanks

Comment: Ah, there is actually a way to do this using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089376/hibernate-id-via-inheritance depends on whether or not you want a unified ID generation, or if you could potentially want separate ID generators for each type of user, i.e. BU has IDs that start with 7.

Comment: @Compass This helps. It also lead me to a few more topics/questions which also help me out and answered my questions. Thank you!